# I need to extract a qtimedate from a qstring

Tags: datetime, qstring, time-format

The qstring comes from a csv file. the string contains:
"1/2/2016 11:59:59 PM: PROCESSED DATA ORIGINAL"
I suspect that: PROCESSED DATA ORIGINAL    s
I read the csv data into a qvector of structures all variables are QStrings
so my variable containing the qstring is MyArray[I].date

QString as = MyArray[I].date;
QDateTime tvar = QDateTime::fromString(as,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss");

I get compiler error:
variable QDateTime tvar has initializer but incomplete type

Any thoughts on where I went off the rails.

Answer (score 0):

I used a split and put the results into a list.  Unfortunately it split out all the time elements so I put in code to build that back together.   Now I just have a time date.